# Python Regex - check for "123456/2016" pattern

Tags: python, regex

I want to check if a registry matches a pattern like "76/2016", "1454/2016", "153432/2013". Technically, before the dash there can be any combination of numbers of up to 6 characters (could be 2, could be 5, there is no specific rule for that) and after the dash there is a set of four numbers (years).

Also, it might happen that some "lost spaces" show up, like " 76/2016 " or "   1454/2016" without a specific rule.

I'm using `re.search(pattern,string)` for that, but I'm having difficulty to write a pattern that fits my needs. Could someone help? I'm a begginer with regex, as you can see...

Comment: You said that you *have a set of codes*. Do you want to check if each code matches a pattern? What should be the final result? Give some example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> before the dash there can be any combination of numbers of up to 6 characters

- Your example doesn't even have a *dash*, but does have a *slash* "/".
- You only show digits, but you say "up to 6 **characters**".

Presuming you mean:

- Zero or more spaces,
- 1-6 digits,
- a slash
- a 4-digit year

Try the following:

```
foo = re.compile("\s*(\d{1,6})/(\d{4})")
for text in list_of_strings:
    match = foo.match(text)
    if match:
        num, year = map(int, match.groups())
        print("Good: %d / %d" % (num, year))
    else:
        print("Bad: \"%s\"" % text)
```

Comment: sorry about the dash, slash confusion

Answer (score 1):

You mention that you want to match.  You may want to try [re.match](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)  Match objects are always `true`, and `None` is returned if there is no match.

```
import re
data = """76/2016
23376/2016
aasss
3376/2016"""

pat = re.compile(r'\d{1,6}/\d{4}')

if re.match(pat,data):
    print('A match')
```

(Out)

```
A match
```

Answer (score 0):

```
re.search(r'\d{1,6}/\d{4}', string)
```